# Reduce number of queries for JPQL POJO containing an entity

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql

Entity relation: Transaction(@ManyToOne - eager by default) -> Account

```
String sql = "SELECT new com.test.Pojo(t.account, SUM(t.value)) FROM Transaction t GROUP BY t.account";
List list = entityManager.createQuery(sql).getResultList();
```

By default JPA using Hibernate implementation will generate 1 + n queries. The n queries are for lazy loading of the account entities.

How can I make this query eager and load everything with a single query? The sql equivalent would be something like

```
SELECT account.*, SUM(t.value) FROM transactions JOIN accounts on transactions.account_id = accounts.id GROUP BY account.id
```

, a syntax that works well on PostgreSQL. From my findings Hibernate is generating a query that justifies the lazy loading.

```
SELECT account.id, SUM(t.value) FROM transactions JOIN accounts on transactions.account_id = accounts.id GROUP BY account.id
```

Comment: I've got to HQLQueryPlan.java inside the hibernate implementation in case somebody wants to go down the rabbit hole. It cleans the HQL before execution.

Comment: Have you tried annotating the Account entity itself with @BatchSize? (sorry, I haven't got time right at the moment to try it out myself and see if that actually helps)

Comment: Please post the relevant mappings.

Comment: The mappings are irelevant for the outcome. @ManyToOne transactions -> account

Answer (score 4):

Try marking the `@ManyToOne` field as lazy:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Account account;
```

And change your query using a `JOIN FETCH` of the `account` field to generate only one query with all you need, like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT new com.test.Pojo(acc, SUM(t.value)) "
    + "FROM Transaction t JOIN FETCH t.account acc GROUP BY acc";
```

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, you're right, the fetch attribute of `@ManyToOne` is not required because in Hibernate that is the default value. The `JOIN FETCH` isn't working, it's causing a `QueryException`: "Query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present".

I have tried with some other approaches, the most simple one that avoids doing n + 1 queries is to remove the creation of the `Pojo` object from your query and process the result list, manually creating the objects:

```
String hql = "SELECT acc, SUM(t.value)"
  + " FROM " + Transaction.class.getName() +  " t"
  + " JOIN t.account acc"
  + " GROUP BY acc";

Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(hql);
List<Pojo> pojoList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object[]> list = query.getResultList();

for (Object[] result : list)
    pojoList.add(new Pojo((Account)result[0], (BigDecimal)result[1]));
```

Comment: 1. why should you put FetchType.LAZY? that's not affecting the ouput in any way for this case; 2. HIbernate can't execute the Join Fetch in this situation.

Comment: I can confirm that using even a simpler query similar with the one I've started String sql = "SELECT t.account, SUM(t.value) FROM Transaction t GROUP BY t.account"; will generate a single query. So this is a solution. My question is: can you instruct Hibernate to do this automatically when mapping to a pojo? It looks like a configuration/implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

Well PostgreSQL (And any other SQL database too) will block you from using mentioned query:  you have to group by all columns of account table, not by id. That is why Hibernate generates the query, grouping by ID of the account - That is what is intended to be, and then fetching the other parts. Because it cannot predict in general way, what else will be needed to be joined and grouped(!!!), and in general this could produce situation, when multiple entities with the same ID are fetched (just create a proper query and take a look at execution plan, this will be especially significant when you have `OneToMany` fields in your `Account` entity, or any other `ManyToOne` part of the `Account` entity) that is why Hibernate behaves this way.

Also, having accounts with mentioned IDs in First level cache, will force Hibernate to pick them up from that. Or IF they are rarely modified entities, you can put them in Second level cache, and hibernate will not make query to database, but rather pick them from Second level cache.

If you need to get those from database in single hint, but not use all the goodness of Hibernate, just go to pure JPA Approach based on Native queries, like this:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "Pojo.groupedInfo",
        query = "SELECT account.*, SUM(t.value) as sum FROM transactions JOIN accounts on transactions.account_id = accounts.id GROUP BY account.id, account.etc ...",
        resultClass = Pojo.class,
        resultSetMapping = "Pojo.groupedInfo")
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "Pojo.groupedInfo",
        classes = {
            @ConstructorResult(
                targetClass = Pojo.class,
                columns =  {
                    @ColumnResult(name = "sum", type = BigDecimal.class),
                    /*
                     * Mappings for Account part of entity.
                     */
                }
            )
        }
   )
 public class Pojo implements Serializable {
     private BigDecimal sum;
     /* .... */
     public Pojo(BigDecimal sum, ...) {}
     /* .... */
}
```

For sure this will work for you well, **unless you will use the Account, fetched by this query in other entities**. This will make Hibernate "mad" - the "entity", but not fetched by Hibernate...

Comment: Actually Psql allows this kind of query where you group by id and select other fields. But It's probably not standard SQL. Still you could group by all the fields and retrieve all the fields, that would be fine in any SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, the described behaviour is as if `t` instances are returned from the actual query and `t.account` association in the first argument of `Pojo` constructor is actually navigated on `t` instances when marshalling results of the query (when creating `Pojo` instances from the result rows of the query). I am not sure if this is a bug or intended feature for constructor expressions.

But the following form of the query should work (no `t.account` navigation in the constructor expression, and no `join fetch` without the owner of the fetched association because it does not make sense to eagerly initialize something that is not actually returned from the query):

```
SELECT new com.test.Pojo(acc, SUM(t.value))
FROM Transaction t JOIN t.account acc
GROUP BY acc
```

**EDIT**

Very good observation by Ilya Dyoshin about the `group by` clause; I completely oversaw it here. To stay in the HQL world, you could simply preload all accounts with transactions before executing the query with grouping:

```
SELECT acc FROM Account acc
WHERE acc.id in (SELECT t.account.id FROM Transaction t)
```

Comment: It doesn't, the explicit JOIN has no extra effect.

Comment: @danidacar Are you accessing anything on passed accounts in the constructor of the `Pojo` instances?

Comment: ofcourse, when I call a property only then the account is lazy loaded, that's the issue